# Loading results text PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need a simple way to show that results are `loading..` from database, while the page loads. I am not using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) to do this.

What I tried now is: I put a `<div>` tag with loading text in it and using [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) I made the display to `none` after the whole while loop. But I don't get to see the text at all.

```
<div id="loading">Loading Results...</div>
```

I put the above code just after the body tag.

I put the below code right after the while loop ending.

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById(\"loading\").style.display = \"none\"</script>";
```

Comment: please correct your typos and mistakes in your question. If you are not getting it right here, how can you expect to get it right in your code?

Comment: sorry. I will correct the typos.

Comment: Why not using jQuery? What is the structure of your page? What the loop that you use?

Comment: I am just fetching the results from MySQL and I am not sure if jQuery filts in here and moreover don't remember much about it. I just used it some long time back.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Have a look at it to see if it fits your bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`flush()`](http://bg.php.net/flush) after the `<div>`. If you are using output buffering it won't work. See the manual for the function.

---

If you don't want the element to be viewable in source the output is using JS. Instead of directly writing the `<div>` in the html write this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="loading">Loading Results...</div>');
</script>

<?php flush() ?>

<!-- output some html -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var loader = document.getElementById('loading');
    loader.parentNode.removeChild( loader );
    // This will not just hide the element, but remove it from the DOM, .
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. that worked. But is there any way to delete that element, so that I do not get to see it when the source is viewed?

Comment: I guess you could hack the behaviour by outputting a style tag to set the loading text visibility to hidden...  It *is* hacky, though. :)

Comment: No, there is no way to remove the element from the viewable source. It can be removed from the DOM tree, but most browsers with a "View Source" feature will show the page as it was first rendered not after JavaScript has had a chance to modify the DOM.

Why would you want it removed? Couldn't you instead then have a loading ... page, then redirect to the actual results page?

Comment: @ZombieSheep: He is already doing that with the JavaScript, hiding the element. He wants it gone when someone right clicks and views the source of the page.

Comment: I am using an image insted of 'loading' text, I do not want that heavy image to take up memory even after the page loads. SO thats why I want to delete that. If I use a temp page that has image and redirect to the page of actual results, then there is extra overhead of requests which I dont want either